# How can I limit the number of widgets I can place into a sidebar in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, sidebar

In Wordpress, have successfully added a sidebar on the homepage, and can add widgets into it.  However I want to be able to limit this to a certain number.  As in when you drag and drop stuff into the sidebar (widget holder) how can I stop it from adding more than 3?

Comment: mb it helps - https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/limit-widgets/ or you want something custom ?

Comment: @mattkrupnik Thank you for replying, yes I would like something custom.  I am programming this.